# Op-amp power sequence

Tags: operational-amplifier, debugging

Two questions and I would like to hear the explanation:

1. Is there any issue to apply the positive voltage before the negative? (op-amp with +/- 5 V)
2. Is there any issue to apply input voltage before the supply voltage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since op-amps generally don't have a (third) ground pin the supply pins only see the difference between the two supply pins. So supply sequence does not really have a meaning from the pov of the op-amp.

In general it is usually safe to keep the signal pins within the supply rails at all times, including during startup (some may additionally restrict the differential input voltage or duration of the presence of a large differential input voltage or the differential input current). If that's not possible, in many cases it's sufficient to limit the current with a series resistor or perhaps to limit the voltage in some way to a few hundred mV outside the rails.

Let the op-amp datasheet and any application notes be your guide.

Applying a low impedance signal of some volts directly to an input before the supply is present can definitely damage some parts, others are fine with it in one polarity, but not in the other, still others may be fine entirely provided the input voltages are not too high.

For example, with the bipolar [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) nominally run from +/-5V supplies, but with supplies at +/-0V, an input of +32V is within abs maximum limits, but an input more negative than -300mV will violate the limits. An [MCP601](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/21314g.pdf) CMOS op-amp will tolerate +/-1V under those conditions (imagine the supply when on is +/-2.5V in that case). A [TL072](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072.pdf) JFET input op-amp +/- 0.5V. Check out superbeta input bipolar op-amps for a somewhat different set of limits.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there any issue to apply the Positive voltage before the Negative?*

For an op-amp, it generally doesn't matter because 0 volts is immaterial to an op-amp other than as a signal reference. However, at any time unpowered, partially powered or fully powered, the inputs should not be allowed to exceed any of the power rails of the op-amp by more than a fraction of a volt usually. This information is provided in the data sheets for most op-amps so, it's the best place to look.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there's.
2. No. The inverting and non-inverting inputs of an op amp are connected to the bases of transistors that form a differential amplifier stage. Without collector and/or emitter supplies the transistors will not be damaged. And as can be seen from the well-known, industry-standard general purpose op amps such as LM358 and LM3x4, input voltage limits are not supply-referenced (e.g. VCC ± 0.3 or VEE ± 0.3).